# Reduction of order: $ y^{(5)}+ y^{(3)} = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I had this question on a quiz but I have really no idea on how to solve this.

> $$y^{(5)} + y^{(3)} = 0$$

We were told to use reduction of orders.

thanks

Comment: Clearly this is equivalent to $y'+y = ax^2+bx+c$ since the null space of the linear operator $D^3$ is just (at most) quadratic polynomials.

Comment: 1) do you know what reduction of orders is? 2) have you used reduction of orders before?

Comment: @AdamHughes:  I think you lost one prime on the first term in your equation.

Comment: @RossMillikan thanks for the catch!

To the op:  $y''+y = ax^2+bx+c$ should be in my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $u = y'''$. Then the equation translates into the second order equation

$$ u'' + u = 0 $$

whose general solution is $u(x) = A \cos(x) + B \sin(x)$. 
Now you are left with solving

$$y'''(x) = \cos(x) \implies y''(x) = \sin(x) + C \implies \\
 y'(x) = -\cos(x) + Cx + D \implies y(x) = -\sin(x) + C'x^2 + Dx + E $$

and

$$ y'''(x) = \sin(x) \implies y''(x) = -\cos(x) + F \implies y'(x) = -\sin(x) + Fx + G \implies\\ y(x) = \cos(x) + F'x^2 + Gx + H. $$

Thus, the general solution is

$$ u(x) = A \cos(x) + B \sin(x) + Cx^2 + Dx + E $$

for $A,B,C,D,E \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thank you for this. Saved me some headaches

Answer (score 0):

Let $f = y^{(3)}$.  Then your equation is $f'' + f = 0$.  By now you should know the linearly independent pair of functions to use here.

> Sine and cosine.

Then integrate three times.  Don't forget the constants of integration (since you don't give any initial conditions), which will result in a quadratic polynomial.

> $\int \int \int \text{sine and cosine stuff} = \int \int (\text{more sine and cosine stuff} + C_1) = \int (\text{yet more sine and cosine stuff} + C_1 x + C_2) = \dots$.

Answer (score 0):

As many have pointed out, using a variable substitution works perfectly fine. This is generalizable:  anytime you have an ODE of the form $y^{(2n+1)}$+ $y^{(2n-1)}$= $0$ we can use the following strategy:

$u=y^{(2n-1)}$ and the ODE becomes $u''+u=0$ which is the classic second-order homogeneous ODE, and we can solve this by back substituting and working through the algebra.